# Unexpected productuil submitting to the Mac App Store

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

So today I was going to upload my Mac app to the App Store. So I create the app id and everything and I make sure that I got everything right and then I find the .app file and compress it to a .zip.
After that I open Application Loader and it finds the created App ID and I get all the info I've filled in on itunes connect and then I click choose to find my .zip file but when I find it it's not selectable.
I also tried to go File > Open and then I was able to select the .zip file and then I selected the App ID etc but when I click send I get these 2 errors:

The archive is invalid. Unexpected productuil output: the prodcut-metadata must be present

and:

Product archive "/User/Kevin/Desktop/Mini Week.zip" is not valid ((null))

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably be using the archiving utility now bundled in Xcode. You can read more about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html).